# How to return new instance with preset fields from a constructor

Tags: java, constructor, return-value

**XHTML:**

```
<p:carousel value="#{carouselView.cars}" var="car" itemStyleClass="carItem">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="width:100%" cellpadding="5" columnClasses="label,value">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <p:graphicImage name="../images/cars/#{car.brand}.gif"/> 
        </f:facet>

        <h:outputText value="Id:" />
        <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />

        <h:outputText value="Year" />
        <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />

        <h:outputText value="Color:" />
        <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" style="color:#{car.color}"/>
```

**Package1 have 1 java file:**
**CarService.java**

```
public class CarService {

    private final static String[] colors;

    private final static String[] brands;

    static {
        colors = new String[10];
        colors[0] = "Black";
        colors[1] = "White";
        colors[2] = "Green";
        colors[3] = "Red";

        brands = new String[10];
        brands[0] = "BMW";
        brands[1] = "Mercedes";
        brands[2] = "Volvo";
        brands[3] = "Audi";
     }
     public List<Car> createCars(int size) {
        List<Car> list = new ArrayList<Car>();
            list.add(new Car(getRandomId(), getRandomBrand(), getRandomYear());

        return list;
    }

    private String getRandomId() {
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 8);
    }

    private int getRandomYear() {
        return (int) (Math.random() * 50 + 1960);
    }

    private String getRandomBrand() {
        return brands[(int) (Math.random() * 10)];
    }


    public List<String> getColors() {
        return Arrays.asList(colors);
    }

    public List<String> getBrands() {
        return Arrays.asList(brands);
    }
}
```

**Package2 have 2 java file:**
**1.CarouselView.java**

```
public class CarouselView implements Serializable {
    private List<Car> cars;
    private Car selectedCar;
    private CarService service;
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        cars = service.createCars(3);
    }

    public List<Car> getCars() {
        return cars;
    }

    public void setService(CarService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public Car getSelectedCar() {
        return selectedCar;
    }

    public void setSelectedCar(Car selectedCar) {
        this.selectedCar = selectedCar;
    }
}
```

**2.Car.java**

```
public class Car {

    String randomId;
    String randomBrand;
    int randomYear;
    public Car(String randomId, String randomBrand, int randomYear) {
        this.randomId = randomId;
        this.randomBrand = randomBrand;
        this.randomYear = randomYear;
    }
}
```

I'm getting error like,

`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.abc.mmc.dto.CarouselView.init(CarouselView.java:35)`

Answer (score 1):

A constructor shouldn't return anything. For typical [POJO's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) (Pretty Ordinary Java Objects) the goal is to just create (or *construct*) your object with the specified arguments.

For example:

```
public class Car {
    private String randomId;
    private String randomBrand;
    private String randomYear;

    public Car(String randomId, String randomBrand, int randomYear) {
        this.randomId = randomId; 
        this.randomBrand = randomBrand;
        this.randomYear = randomYear;
    } 

    //Getters and Setters follow
}
```

`this.randomId = randomId;` You take the argument `randomId` and assign it to the Class variable `this.randomId`

This is common convention. Here is an alternate code fragment to elaborate on intent (though the prior is preferred, assuming your variables are named well):

```
private String carId;
private String carBrand;
private int carYear;

public Car(String randomId, String randomBrand, int randomYear){
   carId = randomId;
   carBrand = randomBrand;
   carYear = randomYear;
}
```

---

If you're passing arguments to a method's constructor and not doing anything with them, it's a waste of time. You're just building naked Objects. It is important to take the incoming parameters and 'design' your `Car` object with those items.

---

**Edit following OP update:**

You're getting a NullPointerException on your `service.createCars(3);` because you aren't initializing your `CarService` object:

```
private Car selectedCar;
private CarService service;
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    service = new CarService(); //Create your service object
    cars = service.createCars(3);
}
```

Comment: @user3114967 Where are those methods located? Within your `Car` class or the same class where `createCars()` is? Because your code implies you're passing parameters to assign attributes to a `Car` Object.

Comment: createCars(int size) and methods are in another file

Comment: Okay. Right now when you pass those values to your `Car` constructor they are being forgotten (you aren't doing anything with your random ID, Brand, and Year). You have to assign and store the values, like in my example.

Comment: I'm getting null pointer exception init method.  public void init() {
        cars = service.createCars(9);
    }

Comment: @user You'll have to give more detail. Edit your post with the changes you made and the stack trace of your error message.

Comment: I've updated my code and what am getting as a error http://stackoverflow.com/q/30109502/3114967                                           how can i get the results?

Comment: @User See my edit. You're getting that error because your init method needs to initialize your `CarService` object before its methods can be utilized.

Comment: also getting Error like,                                                                                                      Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /xhtml/seniortester1.xhtml @51,74
 name="../images/cars/#{car.brands}.gif": Property 'brands' not found on type com.abc.mmc.dto.Car

Comment: @user3114967 That is a different question. You should accept an answer to this post and then create another one.

Answer (score 1):

Constructor does not return anything.
You might want to set some values in the constructor from the arguments into the object.
Something like:

```
public class Car {
    private String randomId;
    private String randomBrand;
    private int randomYear;
    public Car(String randomId, String randomBrand, int randomYear) {
        this.randomId = randomId;
        this.randomBrand = randomBrand;
        this.randomYear = randomYear;
    }
}
```

Comment: ` I've getters like,
     
    private int getRandomYear() {
        return (int) (Math.random() * 50 + 1960);
    }
     
    
    private String getRandomBrand() {
        return brands[(int) (Math.random() * 10)];
    }
     
     private String getRandomId() {
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 8);
    } `

Comment: UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 8) is a bad idea, since it would return non unique more frequently than you expect. Try some other random generator.

Comment: And you might not need a constructor to assign something, since everything is random.so a default constructor should be good enough.

Comment: @Sandeep OP is passing arguments to create new `Car` Objects, it wouldn't make sense if they weren't assigning values therein.

Comment: I've updated my code and what am getting as a error   `http://stackoverflow.com/q/30109502/3114967 ` suggest some way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Constructor can never have a return type even can not have a return type `void` and the constructor name must be similar with the class name. But constructor may be `private` or `public`-

```
private Car(); //or
public Car();
```

From you problem description it seems you need to add some getter/setter method to give access your `private` field in `Car` class.

To work correctly with constructor you don't need to add return statement from it. Any class which create a `Car` instance/object can use the **`new`** operator along with the public constructor -

```
//In some class that need an instance/object
//of Car class
Car aCar = new Car(... //arguments list);
```

**Note:** Here the **`Car()`** is public constructor and it has no return type. In the above statement following things are occurred -
**1.**  JVM create a new instance/object with the public constructor `Car()`
**2.**  The newly created object of type `Car` is assigned with the `Car` type reference variable - aCar.

Answer (score 0):

You need not to return anything. Constructor has no return. It's  has the use of initialization.

Answer (score 0):

In such a simple constructor, I would not return any value at all. With more complexity, relying on external sources especially, I might add a boolean for if construction succeeded or failed.